# why gorm doesn't have BeforeFind hook

Tags: go-gorm

i'm trying to find a way to capture and handle error when using "find".noticed that gorm provide BeforeCreate,AfterCreate pairs to surround create behavior,onle Afterfind could be found,and this can't handle some syntax or execution error unless we have Beforefind.

so why gorm doesn't have beforefind hook